# def block in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, rake

I got `undefined local variable or method 'address_geo' for main:Object` with the following rake task. What's the problem with it?

```
include Geokit::Geocoders

namespace :geocode do
  desc "Geocode to get latitude, longitude and address"
  task :all => :environment do
    @spot = Spot.find(:first)
    if @spot.latitude.blank? && !@spot.address.blank?
      puts address_geo
    end

    def address_geo
      arr = []
      arr << address if @spot.address
      arr << city if @spot.city
      arr << country if @spot.country
      arr.reject{|y|y==""}.join(", ")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It looks like you're calling the function before you define it - have you tried moving the function definition for `address_geo` to the top of the task?

Comment: Yeah, tried, but not working. But I think I dont need this anymore. Thanks.

Comment: Most of the time I want to def a method in a rake task, I find the problem is better solved by just creating a new rake task and invoking it instead: `Rake::Task['cache:clear'].invoke`.  It's easier to read and maintain, and you can run `rake cache:clear` on its own.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

#### Update: Gotcha

This potentially adds the method to global scope and will conflict with any other method with the same name. Look at @Hula_Zell's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44294243/584440 for a better way.

**Original answer**

You are defining the method inside the rake task. For getting the function, you should define outside the rake task (outside the task block). Try this:

```
include Geokit::Geocoders

namespace :geocode do
  desc "Geocode to get latitude, longitude and address"
  task :all => :environment do
    @spot = Spot.find(:first)
    if @spot.latitude.blank? && !@spot.address.blank?
      puts address_geo
    end
  end

  def address_geo
    arr = []
    arr << address if @spot.address
    arr << city if @spot.city
    arr << country if @spot.country
    arr.reject{|y|y==""}.join(", ")
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm doing this and my method became available to all rake tasks, do you know how can I avoid this?

Comment: @WilliamWeckl You can define lambdas inside of the rake task.

Comment: @justingordon What do you mean? What to do?

Comment: Can we call these methods defined inside a rake task from outside the rake file?

Comment: will this method be available only inside that namespace, or for the entire rakefile?

Comment: This method is available inside all rake tasks and it's not safe. Hula_Zell's solution is better.

Comment: Thanks @jamesdevar. I was not aware of this. I thought, since it is inside the namespace, it will be available only for the namespace. Looks like rake namespaces applies only for rake tasks.

Answer (score 35):

#### Careful: Methods defined in rake files end up defined on the global namespace.

I would propose to extract the methods into a module or class. This is because **methods defined in rake files end up defined on the global namespace**. i.e. they can then be called from anywhere, not just within that rake file (even if it is namespaced!).

This also means that if you have two methods with the same name in two different rake tasks, one of them will be overwritten without you knowing it. Very deadly.

A great explanation is available here: https://kevinjalbert.com/defined_methods-in-rake-tasks-you-re-gonna-have-a-bad-time/

Comment: I also think that this is the best practice to extract the methods into a module or class.

Comment: plus one. I wasnt aware of this.

Comment: First time I came here I didn't take the time to read this and it ended up biting me. Everyone should know this potential conflict and either be extremely careful or extract methods to a module that can be required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Proc` to get the same effect without having a global method declaration.  e.g.,

```
include Geokit::Geocoders

namespace :geocode do
  desc "Geocode to get latitude, longitude and address"
  task :all => :environment do

    address_geo = Proc.new do
      arr = []
      arr << address if @spot.address
      arr << city if @spot.city
      arr << country if @spot.country
      arr.reject{|y|y==""}.join(", ")
    end
    @spot = Spot.find(:first)
    if @spot.latitude.blank? && !@spot.address.blank?
      puts address_geo.call
    end
  end
end
```