# rake task error : undefined method 'perform' for main:Object

Tags: ruby, rake

can anybody suggest me where i am going wrong?

i tried to execute below task, but ended up with

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method 'perform' for main:Object
```

this is my rake task

```
task :update_state_for_search_request => :environment do
 t_last = MyModule.where("condition").last.id
 t_first = 0

 until t_first >= t_last do
  t_first=print_id(t_first)
 end 

 def perform(sid)
  # action 
  my_data = MyModule.where("name='abcd' and id > #{sid}").limit(1000)
  # action
  return my_data.last.id
 end  

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining method inside rake task which is the issue here. Define it outside your task.

```
task :update_state_for_search_request => :environment do
 t_last = MyModule.where("condition").last.id
 t_first = 0

 until t_first >= t_last do
  t_first=print_id(t_first)
 end 
end

def perform(sid)
 # action 
 my_data = MyModule.where("name='abcd' and id > #{sid}").limit(1000)
 # action
 return my_data.last.id
end
```

Also refer to this SO: [def block in rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298088/def-block-in-rake-task)